# reactor-core - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full?! on Hot Publisher (ConnectableFlux)

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I had been using RxJava so far but I am starting to play with reactor-core from projectreactor.io since it adheres to the reactive streams spec.

In the following test I create a hot Flux (ConnectableFlux) that generates random numbers. I connect() it immediately and it prefetches 256 values (I can see 258 actually them in the log). I wait 5 seconds to simulate that the subscriber won't subscribe until some time later.

After the main thread wakes up, the RnApp subscribes to the ConnectableFlux, `randomNumberGenerator.subscribe(new RnApp());`. Then `RnApp.onSubscribe()` is called and 10 elements are requested. After that, a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full?!` exception is raised (`RnApp.onError()` is invoked), why?

**Subscriber**:

```
public class RnApp implements Subscriber<Float>{

    private Subscription subscription;
    private List<Float> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<Float>();

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        System.out.println("onComplete");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Float f) {
        if(this.randomNumbers.size()>=10){
            this.subscription.cancel();
        }else{
            this.randomNumbers.add(f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription subs) {
        this.subscription = subs;
        this.subscription.request(10);
    }
}
```

**Publisher test**:

```
@Test
public void randomNumberReading() throws InterruptedException {

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    ConnectableFlux<Float> randomNumberGenerator = ConnectableFlux.<Float>create( (c) -> {
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        int i = 1;
        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------"+(i++));
            c.onNext(sr.nextFloat());
        }
    }).log().subscribeOn(Computations.concurrent()).publish();

    randomNumberGenerator.connect();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    randomNumberGenerator.subscribe(new RnApp());

    latch.await();
}
```

**Log**:

```
11:12:05.125 [main] DEBUG r.core.util.Logger$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
11:12:05.363 [concurrent-1] INFO  reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog -  onSubscribe(io.pivotal.literx.Part10SubscribeOnPublishOn$$Lambda$1/1586600255@29d4caeb)
11:12:05.371 [concurrent-1] INFO  reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog -  request(256)
-----------------------------------------------------1
11:12:06.000 [concurrent-1] INFO  reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog -  onNext(0.39189225)
-----------------------------------------------------2
...
-----------------------------------------------------257
11:12:08.683 [concurrent-1] INFO  reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog -  onNext(0.34729618)
-----------------------------------------------------258
11:12:08.697 [concurrent-1] INFO  reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog -  onNext(0.7729547)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full?!
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$State.onNext(FluxPublish.java:246)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnPipeline.onNext(FluxSubscribeOn.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog$LoggerBarrier.doNext(FluxLog.java:130)
    at reactor.core.subscriber.SubscriberBarrier.onNext(SubscriberBarrier.java:85)
    at reactor.core.subscriber.SubscriberWithContext.onNext(SubscriberWithContext.java:92)
    at io.pivotal.literx.Part10SubscribeOnPublishOn.lambda$1(Part10SubscribeOnPublishOn.java:132)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGenerate$ForEachBiConsumer.accept(FluxGenerate.java:145)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGenerate$ForEachBiConsumer.accept(FluxGenerate.java:114)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGenerate$SubscriberProxy.request(FluxGenerate.java:245)
    at reactor.core.subscriber.SubscriberBarrier.doRequest(SubscriberBarrier.java:146)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog$LoggerBarrier.doRequest(FluxLog.java:160)
    at reactor.core.subscriber.SubscriberBarrier.request(SubscriberBarrier.java:135)
    at reactor.core.util.DeferredSubscription.set(DeferredSubscription.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnPipeline.onSubscribe(FluxSubscribeOn.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog$LoggerBarrier.doOnSubscribe(FluxLog.java:122)
    at reactor.core.subscriber.SubscriberBarrier.onSubscribe(SubscriberBarrier.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGenerate.subscribe(FluxGenerate.java:72)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog.subscribe(FluxLog.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SourceSubscribeTask.run(FluxSubscribeOn.java:363)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Computations$ProcessorWorker.onNext(Computations.java:919)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Computations$ProcessorWorker.onNext(Computations.java:883)
    at reactor.core.publisher.WorkQueueProcessor$QueueSubscriberLoop.run(WorkQueueProcessor.java:842)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with RxJava, if you are using `create()`, you are on your own dealing with cancellation and backpressure. You could instead build the generator from standard operators:

```
ConnectableFlux<Double> secureRandomFlux = Flux.using(
    () -> new SecureRandom(),
    sr -> Flux.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          .map(v -> sr.nextDouble())
          .onBackpressureDrop()
    sr -> { }
).publish();
```

Comment: thanks for anwering. A couple of questions: 1) the idea is that secureRandomFlux is shared (can be subscribed by several Subscribers. Flux.using states: `Uses a resource, generated by a supplier for each individual Subscriber` does this mean that the flux would provide different random values for each subscriber? 2) In the original case, how can I deal with backpressure using create()?

Comment: Anybody listening to secureRandomFlux at the same time will get the same exact value - it appeared as your intention. You have to track the request amount of the subscriber and check if they are ready to receive a value.

Comment: Everythinng cleared up :-) One last thing. Regarding hot observables, in this case I don't mind prefetching values, but in the case of a real time source (e.g: a sensor) I wouldn't like to prefetch anything. However we are forced to set a value >=1 in `publish(n)`. Do you know a way of not prefetching? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Edited my answer to add publish + delaySubscription.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think reactor has a SimpleProcessor  (~ RxJava PublishSubject) which does multicasting without prefetch.

Comment: @smaldini That's a good workaround when you only have one subscriber but it doesn't work for +1.

Comment: You can use `EmitterProcessor.create()` + `connectEmitter()` to onSubscribe it with a SignalEmitter you can use to push and drop on Emission.BACKPRESSURED if you want.

Answer (score 3):

`create()` expects one onNext per callback invokation. Alternatively you can check `Flux.yield` which gives you extra emitting methods to handle downstream state (backpressure or cancelled). Or you could use `Flux.generate` which is like `create` but is invoked once per request so you can effectively `onNext` up to the passed demand.

These 3 `Flux` generators are currently debated so we could discuss better alternatives on http://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues.

You can also prevent publish prefetching with Flux#delaySubscription, e.g. with latest snapshot UnicastProcessor :

```
 UnicastProcessor<Object> p = UnicastProcessor.create();
 flux.delaySubscription(p).publish(128).autoConnect().subscribe();

 //...
 p.onNext(new Object());
```